# IOS application failing with communicating with HTTPS server with GoDaddy SSL certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, ios9

I am developing iOS application that is communicating to the HTTPS server which has GoDaddy certificate installed (https://www.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate - first option).

This is the error log

```
    CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2016-03-21 16:58:37.853 [2451:2129735] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x13f5cb700 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://******.com:9001/api/terms/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://******.com:9001/api/terms/, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3})
Server error
2016-03-21 16:58:37.927 [2451:2129735] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2016-03-21 16:58:37.928 [2451:2129735] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
```

I used ssllabs to test certificate and these are results:

```
Signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA
Key: RSA 2048 bits (e 65537)
Issuer: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2 
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   INSECURE    Yes
SSL 2   No
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) 112
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x16)   DH 2048 bits   FS    112
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  112
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)   INSECURE   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 2048 bits   FS 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x41)    128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x45)   DH 2048 bits   FS    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x96)    128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x9a)   DH 2048 bits   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   INSECURE    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 2048 bits   FS 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x84)    256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x88)   DH 2048 bits   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
```

And this is specific for iOS9 handshake:

```
Protocol Details
Server Name Indication (SNI)    Yes
Secure Renegotiation    Yes
TLS compression No
Session tickets No
OCSP stapling   Yes
Signature algorithms    SHA384/RSA, SHA256/RSA, SHA1/RSA,   SHA384/ECDSA,   SHA256/ECDSA,   SHA1/ECDSA
Elliptic curves secp256r1,  secp384r1,  secp521r1
Next Protocol Negotiation   Yes
Application Layer Protocol Negotiation  Yes   h2 h2-16 h2-15 h2-14 spdy/3.1 spdy/3 http/1.1
SSL 2 handshake compatibility   No
```

Any advice on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does Google Chrome show any certificate errors when you browse to that URL?

Comment: As I can see, If I run it using apache server with php application on 443 port then it shows `The connection uses TLS 1.2.`. If I run Django application (that I need) using `https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver`, then it shows `The connection uses TLS 1.0.`. I guess the main issue here is in the that server that I run on django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that this module that I used for running ssl server (https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) is not actually working properly and it uses the certificate but revokes TLS1.2